# Why this equality returns False on Scilab?

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, equality, scilab

I am learning Scilab for educational purposes.

When dealing with Gaussian Elimination we have that Ax=b. "A" is the matrix with the coefficients from the linear equations, "x" is the vector with the variables and "b" is the vector with the "solutions" from the linear system.

Let's suppose A is:

```
    10.  - 7.      0.  
  - 3.     2.09    6.  
    5.   - 1.      5.
```

And b is:

```
7.    
3.91  
6.
```

Using the Gaussian elimination inside Scilab, we get the values of x as:

```
  - 3.109D-14  
  - 1.         
    1.
```

Obs: - 3.109D-14 is a number close to zero.

When I do the matrix multiplication as A*x, I get a 3x1 vector with the same components as vector "b":

[image]

Finally, my doubt is: if A*x has the same values as "b", why the equality bellow returns False in Scilab?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to the rounding error, and the inherent limitations of the floating point math, as indicated by Normal Human in his comment.

Another thing to remember: the Scilab console outputs rounded values, so internally there are usually more decimal places that are not shown, unless asked explicitly, e.g. `mprintf("x= %.30f", x(1));`

To circumvent this problem, you can try to `clean` your array, that is, round the very small enties to 0. Try to see the result of:

```
A*clean(x)==b
```